# Executing Uninstall String with parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, execute, uninstallstring

I get the following uninstall string from the registry:

```
$uninstallstring = MsiExec.exe /X{123-12323-123213-A6123-123123}"
```

I can execute this string with:

```
cmd /c $uninstallstring
```

That works but I want to execute it with the parameters /quiet and /norestart.
But if I try to append the parameters, I cannot execute the uninstall string:

```
$uninstallstring+=" /quiet /norestart"
cmd /c $uninstallstring
```

How to execute the uninstall string with these parameters in Powershell?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you share the output of $uninstallstring after adding the additional flags. I'd like to see how it spits it out before I give my advice. Thanks -

Comment: MsiExec.exe /X{123-12323-123213-A6123-123123} /quiet /norestart

Comment: But I have another problem: If I execute MsiExec.exe /X{123-12323-123213-A6123-123123}  with cmd, it says the the product is successfully uninstalled. But actually the product still exists. In the braces this is the upgrade code. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Your code is missing an opening `"`. If that is just a posting artifact, then there's no obvious problem with your attempt. If the `Uninstall-Package` approach doesn't work for you and you still have a problem (as indicated in your previous comment), I suggest asking a _new_ question.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell 5.1, this should work with whatever the name is of the msi install.

```
uninstall-package 'google chrome'
```